MAC Sequoia Windows Open When On Header
Sometimes when I'm straightening out my browser, the window gets all big. Something with the header (Post Thread area), some setting maybe, it hasnt done until now. I know there was a setting, like this. Double click a windows title bar, and when I was double clicking the tab bar the window sometimes got big too.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you talking about the new window tiling feature? You can drag windows near edges to automatically size them to full screen, or left half, right half etc. If you don't like that, turn it off in System Settings → Desktop & Dock → Windows - Tile by dragging windows to screen edges.
